# How do you use gzip in .htaccess or php.ini?

Tags: .htaccess, webserver, gzip, php

I'm looking for a simple one line code that will use gzip to compress css, html, js, and php files on the web server. How can I do this with the .htaccess file or php.ini file? (My css and js files are in seperate folders in the root directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're most likely looking for [mod_deflate module in Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html). Enable it in your `httpd.conf` and also enable .htaccess then add this code in your .htaccess under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
<FilesMatch "\\.(js|css|html|htm|php)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<Files *>
    #Compress
    SetOutputFilter GZIP
</Files>
```